# Creating a service for user (S4U) token

Tags: windows, security

The Windows Task Scheduler can create tasks that run with the account of a particular user, without storing the user password. They call it "S4U", service for user. This should work something like the scheduler creates such a token for the current user and can use it to run the scheduled process under that user account. They claim that it cannot access network or encrypted resources with this system. The scheduler itself runs with the SYSTEM account for it to work. Here's an [article that describes it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163350.aspx#S3). The relevant quote from it:

> TASK_LOGON_S4U is yet another option that provides a more secure
>   alternative. It takes advantage of a service for user (S4U) logon to
>   run the task on behalf of the specified user, but without having to
>   store the password. Since the Task Scheduler runs within the local
>   system account, it can create a S4U logon session and receive a token
>   that can not only be used for identification, but also for
>   impersonation on the local computer. Normally a S4U token is only good
>   for identification.

I need to use this authentication scheme in my application, but can't let the Task Scheduler do it but need to do it myself, because I need it for any number of accounts. Whenever a user registers a task with my application, any followup tasks must run under the same user. But since they cannot overlap, I need to do the serialisation myself.

I cannot find any information about this "S4U" thing. How could I implement it in my application? C# preferred, but WINAPI and C is okay.

Update: This is what I've tried, and it doesn't work.

```
// The WindowsIdentity(string) constructor uses the new
// Kerberos S4U extension to get a logon for the user
// without a password.
WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(identity);
WindowsImpersonationContext wic = null;
try
{
  wic = wi.Impersonate();
  // Code to access network resources goes here.
}
catch()
{
  // Ensure that an exception is not propagated higher in the call stack.
}
finally
{
  // Make sure to remove the impersonation token
  if( wic != null)
    wic.Undo();
}
```

But I've got the impression now, that you can't just say you want to be a certain user. Not even as System. You need to be logged in as that user and can generate some token that allows you to become that user later again, without the password. So this must be a two-step thing, first I need to get the token and store it on disk; later I can use that token to impersonate. None of the examples explains this.

Comment: An MSDN search seems to provide all the information you need: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=S4U&emptyWatermark=true&ac=4 ; in particular, the LsaLogonUser API function does all the heavy lifting.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That doesn't help me. I don't know how to use this API, there is no working example. Also I'm not with WCF or ASP.NET, and the computer may or may not be joined to a domain. I've tried the simple `WindowsIdentity` constructor but it said there is nothing to validate this info, or something. Sounds like it requires a domain controller. But Task Scheduler can do without.

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  Did you look at the example code [in the first article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188757.aspx)?

Comment: Edited my question about what does not work. While the first article looks like Domain Controller and Server-only, and the code is completely unreadable, I will give it a try back home (on a non-domain machine).

Comment: Does the process have the "Act as part of the operating system" privilege?  Where does the code fail, and with what error code or exception?

Answer (score 0):

"The computer may not be joined to the domain"

S4U requires access to a KDC. S4U is actually two protocols. S4U2Self and S4U2Proxy. What it is doing is using an addition to Kerberos to get service tickets for a user, but that account that goes and gets the ticket has to have a special delegation enabled on it. [See here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720385(v=ws.10).aspx) for this set up.

But unless you are actually letting the process die etc, why not just get the users service ticket or TGT? Is your application local or is it a service running remote to the user?

Task scheduler needs to go get a new one because a service ticket isn't valid forever. Or in some delegation schemes the user hasn't passed a service ticket to the Application Server and then the AS goes and requests and service ticket via S4U2Self, and then uses that service ticket to request a ticket to a second service via S4U2Proxy.

Comment: So does it fail to get new ones on reboot? On Windows Server 2016 Standard edition I see jobs that try to log on as batch work, set to not keep user password work fine till reboot. From then on it fails. Will change to save password for now. To change to that I had to disable (which is the default) a policy setting that had been enabled to not store passwords locally, wonder if that is also affecting storage/renewal of S4U token somehow (e.g. keeping it in memory and failing to store and have after reboot)